# Simulate traffic over virtual com port

Tags: c++, testing

I'm having a project with Arduino(s) and I would like to build a testing environment so I will be able to do end-to-end integration before testing on the real stuff.

I have a C# program that controls the actions sent to an Arduino, using serial port. The Arduino do some calculations and send back the results back to the C# controller.

I do not want to change the C# program. I do have to implement a program that runs the arudino code and transmit it to a virtual com port I've already created, so the C# program could read it.

Can you please give me some guidance how to write to the virtual com port ?
The Arduino is written in C++, so I guess the solution should be implemented in C++ also.

I noticed to the existance of the tcomport, but it's written in Delphi, so I can't see how I can use it with the C++ code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will be closed pretty quickly, since you're looking for a tool or library, which is technically off-topic.

That being said, you might want to check out [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). This creates a couple fake comport that are "connected together". You would have your program use one, then write another program that simulates the Arduino connected to the other port.

Another solution is to have an interface abstraction between your code and the serial port code. You can then implement that interface to pretend to accept data written to the fake "com port" and produce whatever data you wish in response. This way, you can have the "loopback" and "simulator" contained within your own code.

Comment: I was just looking for guidance so I will have a direction how to start. I will try your first solution, seems more simple. Thank you very much.